# AVL / Binary Search Tree

Tags: c, algorithm, binary-tree, avl-tree

I have a C programming question. The below is a insert to a node with a key.

I don't understand why `node->left = insert(node->left,key)`

I assume this code WILL update the `node->left` with what?

Isn't it calling `insert()` again? It's like calling the same function again and again isn't it a infinite loop or insert calling?

I checked a few example, they are all updating the `node->left` that way by calling the same function again? Let's say I misunderstood, what are the storing in it? The pointer? Or are they just magically linked?

```
// An AVL tree node
struct node
{
    int key;
    struct node *left;
    struct node *right;
    int height;
};

struct node* insert(struct node* node, int key)
{
    /* 1.  Perform the normal BST rotation */
    if (node == NULL)
        return(newNode(key));

    if (key < node->key)
        node->left  = insert(node->left, key);//This just called Insert function again?
    else
        node->right = insert(node->right, key);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, they are calling the `insert` function again, but note that the arguments have changed<sup>1</sup>. This is what is called [recursion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_(computer_science)).

Also note that it does not *always* call the same function again: in case `node==NULL` it does not call it. So this is not infinite; as you take `node->left`, `node->left->left` and so one, you once come to a point where the pointer is `NULL`.

---

<sup>1</sup> I don't say that recursive call *must* always change its arguments, but that's the most common approach.

Comment: Why does it need to call itself to store to node->left

Comment: @FlyingAtom, do you understand the algorithm behind this code? Or do you understand binary search trees in general?

Comment: Uh, I know how AVL works visually but in terms of code I'm sort of new to C, Came from PHP background.

Comment: @FlyingAtom, this is not even about AVL; just for any BST if you perform an insert, you look into which subtree to insert and then you can either loop down the tree, or just call the `insert()` recursively.

Comment: I dont undersatnd how I can just keep calling insert and it will add it to the "end of the tree". I assume something like, insert will loop until it hits the end and insert itself then update the parent either left/right node?

Comment: @FlyingAtom Refer this: [AVL Insert Operation](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/avl-tree-set-1-insertion/)

Comment: Note that every time you call it to a child of a current node. So first call has, say, `node==root`, next has `node==root->left`, next has `node==root->left->left` and so on. It definitely will come to the end of the tree. (And if you did not know, each function call will have its own `node`.)

Comment: AHhhh Until it hit's the NULL and it will call the Insert node function. I get it now HAHAHA OMG THANKS!

Comment: @Petr Do you have any advice on reading my AVL after i finish inserting. I will be inserting multiple of 1- 5. After that , I would like to count how many of each 1-5 are there inside. Any advice or guide? I cant really find any on Iterating

Comment: @FlyingAtom, this is at least a very broad question both for comments and for this site even if posted as a standalone. So I suggest you get a good book on BSTs (and on C probably) and read them.